# How do you extract the javaScript code from a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

I've to refactor a bunch of html files containing a mix of html and javascript code.
I'd like to isolate the javascript code to be able to use various tools (for instance gjslint).

Is there a tool to do that automatically ? (I did search but wasn't able to find anything, maybe using the wrong terms.)

thanks...

Comment: Your best of migrating the javascript by hand so that you can refactor and improve it at the same time. I can't imagine auto extracted code being nice.

Comment: Yes, once you've grabbed all the JS code you should move it over to external .js files.

Comment: too many files to do it by hand :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to get the javascript with javascript you can use jQuery like so

```
$('script').each(function(){ 
    alert($(this).html()) 
});
```

Comment: Nice! 

I like how your mind works ;-)

Might be more practical to write out the JS to an HTML element to facilitate easier copying though -


    $("#MyJSDiv").text($(this).html());

Comment: It's really a useful function but I want to run the code instead of alert it

Answer (score 3):

[WebDeveloperToolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) plugin to Firefox has an option Information->View Javascript that will list all inline scirpts and all included scripts and here you can cut and paste what you need.

It will all be presented as a single webpage with collapsable section for each scripttag and external file.

But eventhandlers like `<a href"" onclick="">` will not be listed unfortunatly.

This also works on any webpage without having to edit them first.

Answer (score 2):

If you install [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) there is a tab called "script" which displays the content of all files with JavaScripts.

EDIT: Just realized that it won't help you much if the scripts are inline. If it's included from various other files, it's still useful though.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the editor you're using, but you could do a RegularExpression search and extract blocks of text in the HTML/JS mix that is enclosed in `<script></script>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract only the tags then you can try it with this site: https://js-download.com/

Here are the tags extracted and the result will be merged to one file.

Comment: This website is no longer online.